# parent pass argument to child using execlp

Tags: c

first, I'm trying to read from a file and pass it to child process using execlp 
but execlp won't work.

second, how can the child read the char which execlp has passed and return a boolean value?

this is the process which read and pass

```
int main() { 
  FILE *file;
  char c, cc;
  file = fopen("input.txt","r");
    if(file == NULL){
      printf("File doesn't exist");
}
else
{
    while ((c = fgetc(file))!= EOF){
     cc =getc(file);
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
 if (pid < 0)
  {
   exit(-1);
  }
 else 
  if (pid == 0) /* We are in the child. */
   {
    execlp("LowAlpha","LowAlpha", cc,(char*) NULL);
    exit(0);
   }
  else
   {
     wait(0);           
     exit(0); 
   }
    }
}
    fclose(file);
    return 0 ;  
    }
```

and this is the child

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char cc = *argv[0];   
    printf("%c",  cc," . \n");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please note that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) return an **`int`**. This is actually very important for the comparison against `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

One major problem is in your call to `execlp`:

```
execlp("LowAlpha","LowAlpha", cc,(char*) NULL);
```

You cast the terminating `NULL` pointer to `char *` (even though it's not needed), but you forget that the previous argument `cc` is *not* a `char *`. The variable `cc` is a single `char`, but you're supposed to pass null-terminated strings to the `exec` function family.

You can solve this by using [*compound literals*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) like in

```
// Construct a temporary null-terminated string to pass
execlp("LowAlpha"," LowAlpha", (char[]){ cc, '\0' }, NULL);
```

---

As for getting a result back from the external program, you have two choices:

1. Create a pipe connected to the child `stdout` stream, which you can then read normal output; Or
2. Get the exit code from the child process (what the external program return from the `main` function) from the [`wait`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) function.

If you just want to get a "boolean" okay/fail from the external program, I recommend using the second way, by getting the exit code from the external program using the [`wait`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) function:

```
// In parent
int status;
wait(&status);

if (WIFEXITED(status))
{
    // Child process exited normally
    int retval = WEXITSTATUS(status);

    printf("Child exited with %d\n", retval);
}
```